# Class with parent class has many items - not possible with mapping-by-code

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm having a problem with nHibernate: If an entity inherits from a base entity, then this child entity cannot be referenced by another entity.

---

I have an inheritance hierarchy in my database as follows:

- `VideoFeed` IS A `VisualFeed`
- `VideoFeed` has many `PlaylistAssignment`

Here's the (paraphrased) SQL definition

```
create table VisualFeed
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL  -- Primary key
)

create table VideoFeed
(
   id BIGINT NOT NULL   -- Primary key, foriegn key references VisualFeed
)

create table PlaylistAssignment
(
   id BIGINT NOT NULL,   -- Primary key
   VideoFeed_Id BIGINT NOT NULL   -- Foreign key to VideoFeed
)
```

And the class definitions

```
public class VisualFeed 
{
    public virtual long? Id { get; set; }
}

public class VideoFeed : VisualFeed
{
    public virtual ISet<PlaylistAssignment> PlaylistAssignments { get; set; }
}

public class PlaylistAssignment
{
    public virtual long? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual VideoFeed VideoFeed { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the mapping code for `VisualFeed` (the parent class):

```
public static void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
{
mapper.Class<DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.VisualFeed>(
        classMapper =>
        {
            classMapper.Table("cms_VisualFeed");
            classMapper.Id(
                            visualFeed => visualFeed.Id,
                            idMapper =>
                            {
                                idMapper.Column("Id");
                                idMapper.Generator(Generators.HighLow,
                                                    generatorMapper =>
                                                    {
                                                        generatorMapper.Params(

                                                            new
                                                            {
                                                                max_lo = 256,
                                                                column = "NextHi",
                                                                where = "TableName='VisualFeed'"
                                                            }
                                                        );
                                                    }
                                );
                            }
            );
    });
}
```

Here's the mapping code for `VideoFeed`:

```
public static void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
{
    mapper.JoinedSubclass<DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.VideoFeed>(
            joinedSubClassMapper =>
            {
                joinedSubClassMapper.Table("cms_VideoFeed");
                joinedSubClassMapper.Key(keyMapper =>
                    {
                        keyMapper.Column("Id");
                    }
                );


                joinedSubClassMapper.Set(
                    playerGroup => playerGroup.PlaylistAssignments,
                    setPropertiesMapper =>
                    {
                        setPropertiesMapper.Key(
                                keyMapper =>
                                {
                                    keyMapper.Column("VideoFeed_Id");
                                    keyMapper.PropertyRef(videoFeed => videoFeed.Id);
                                }
                            );
                        setPropertiesMapper.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
                        setPropertiesMapper.Inverse(true);
                        setPropertiesMapper.OrderBy(playlistAssignment => playlistAssignment.AssignmentRank);
                    },
                    collectionElementRelation =>
                    {
                        collectionElementRelation.OneToMany();
                    }
                );    
            }
            );
}
```

And the mapping code for `PlaylistAssignment':

```
public static void Map(ModelMapper mapper)
{

    mapper.Class<DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.PlaylistAssignment>(
            classMapper =>
            {
                classMapper.Table("cms_PlaylistAssignment");
                classMapper.Id(
                    playlistAssignment => playlistAssignment.Id,
                    idMapper =>
                    {
                        idMapper.Generator(Generators.Identity);
                    }

                    );

                classMapper.ManyToOne(
                        pa => pa.VideoFeed,
                        manyToOneMapper =>
                        {
                            manyToOneMapper.Column("VideoFeed_Id");
                            manyToOneMapper.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
                        }
                    );
           });
 };
```

An exception gets thrown when when calling `ModelMapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities`.

The exception is thrown inside nHibernate code, in the file [KeyMapper.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Mapping/ByCode/Impl/KeyMapper.cs):

```
public void PropertyRef(MemberInfo property)
{
   if (property == null)
   {
       mapping.propertyref = null;
       return;
   }
   if (!ownerEntityType.Equals(property.DeclaringType) && !ownerEntityType.Equals(property.ReflectedType))
   {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("property", "Can't reference a property of another entity.");
   }
   mapping.propertyref = property.Name;
}
```

`ownerEntityType` equals "VideoFeed", and both `ReflectedType` and `DeclaringType` equals "VisualFeed" (the parent class name). Even though this is all correct, the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` gets thrown.

---

Can anyone think of a workaround?

---

**Later Edit** This problem was caused by explicit reference calls to `setPropertiesMapper`. It was actually on a different child class which I had ommitted from the question (in a misguided attempt at simplifiying the problem).

The actual culprit is in the mapping to 'cms_VisualFeedAssignment' below:

```
        mapper.Class<DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.VisualFeed>(
                classMapper =>
                {
                    classMapper.Table("cms_VisualFeed");
                    classMapper.Id(
                                    visualFeed => visualFeed.Id,
                                    idMapper =>
                                    {
                                        idMapper.Column("Id");
                                        idMapper.Generator(Generators.HighLow,
                                                            generatorMapper =>
                                                            {
                                                                generatorMapper.Params(

                                                                    new
                                                                    {
                                                                        max_lo = 256,
                                                                        column = "NextHi",
                                                                        where = "TableName='VisualFeed'"
                                                                    }
                                                                );
                                                            }
                                        );
                                    }
                    );
                 classMapper.Set<DATMedia.CMS.EntityLibrary.Entities.VisualFeedAssignment>(
                                    visualFeed => visualFeed.Assignments,
                                    bagPropertiesMapper =>
                                    {
                                        bagPropertiesMapper.Inverse(true);
                                        bagPropertiesMapper.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);
                                        bagPropertiesMapper.Key(
                                            keyMapper =>
                                            {
                                                keyMapper.Column("VisualFeed_Id");
                                                //keyMapper.PropertyRef<long?>(visualFeed => visualFeed.Id);
                                            }
                                        );
                                        bagPropertiesMapper.Table("cms_VisualFeedAssignment");
                                    },
                                    collectionElementRelation =>
                                    {
                                        collectionElementRelation.OneToMany();
                                    }
                                );
                        }
                    );
            }
```

When I commented out the `PropertyRef` call, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this line:

```
keyMapper.PropertyRef(videoFeed => videoFeed.Id);
```

The `VideoFeed.Id` would automatically be referenced. Try removing that line, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The mapping now completes, but an exception gets thrown in a different part of the code. I've updated my question with the new error.

Comment: There's something else going on in your code. Could you provide the mapping for PlaylistAssignment? And what version of NH are you running?

Comment: OK, I've added the PlaylistAssignment mapping. I'm using nHibernate 3.3.1 right now. I was going to upgrade to 3.3.2, but it seems you can only download the binaries, not the code package. (Do you know if the code has been packaged into a zip file on any site?)

Comment: NH 3.3.2 source is on http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.3.2GA/

Comment: I don't get any exceptions with your mapping on NH 3.3.1 and 3.3.2. I've posted a test project here: https://github.com/thilaknathen/StackOverflow-14133330. The basic structure that you've posted here works fine. There's something somewhere else that's failing. Try stripping your mappings down to the bare structure you've posted here and add the other mappings you might have on the objects incrementally till you hit the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for doing this. I downloaded your example, and it worked for me too. It turned out there was another Set hanging off VisualFeedAssignment that also used the keyMapper.PropertyRef method. When I took that out, it all started working. (What is keyMapper.PropertyRef for, anyway).

Comment: PropertyRef is for associations where the join happens on a property that is the primary key. It's usually used for legacy databases where you can't change the db schema.